# Let $m$ be the largest real root of the equation $\frac3{x-3} + \frac5{x-5}+\frac{17}{x-17}+\frac{19}{x-19} =x^2 - 11x -4$ find $m$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, radicals, substitution

> Let $m$ be the largest real root of the equation $$\frac3{x-3} + \frac5{x-5}+\frac{17}{x-17}+\frac{19}{x-19} =x^2 - 11x -4.$$ Find $m$.

do we literally add all the fractions or do we do something else 
I have no clue how to solve this

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source of the problem, its motivation, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: For advice on how to write a good question, including when you don't know how to begin, please see "How to ask a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I think we don't need to close this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**HINT:**

Write the LHS as $$\left(\frac x{x-3}-1\right)+\left(\frac x{x-5}-1\right)+\left(\frac x{x-17}-1\right)+\left(\frac x{x-19}-1\right)$$ and this gives a constant term of $-4$. Equating this with the RHS, we have$$x\left(\frac1{x-3}+\frac1{x-5}+\frac1{x-17}+\frac1{x-19}\right)=x(x-11)$$ and note that $3,5$ are 'symmetrical' around $11$; that is, $17-11=11-5$ and $19-11=11-3$.

Comment: So how do you finish it

Comment: Due to the 'symmetry', we know that there is a factor of $x-11$ on the LHS. Then divide through by $x(x-11)$ so equate to zero.

Answer (score 6):

We need to solve
$$\frac3{x-3}+1+ \frac5{x-5}+1+\frac{17}{x-17}+1+\frac{19}{x-19}+1 =x^2 - 11x $$ or
$$x\left(\frac{1}{x-3} + \frac{1}{x-5}+\frac{1}{x-17}+\frac{1}{x-19}\right) =x^2 - 11x$$ or
$$2x(x-11)\left(\frac{1}{(x-3)(x-19)}+\frac{1}{(x-5)(x-17)}\right)=x(x-11),$$ which gives $x_1=0$, $x_2=11$ or
$$\frac{1}{x^2-22x+57}+\frac{1}{x^2-22x+85}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
Let $x^2-22x+57=a$.

Thus, $$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{a+28}=\frac{1}{2}$$ or
$$a^2+24a-56=0$$ or
$$a^2+24a+144=200,$$ which gives
$$a=-12+10\sqrt2$$ or
$$a=-12-10\sqrt2,$$
which gives 
$$x^2-22x+69\pm10\sqrt2=0$$ or
$$x^2-22x+121=52\pm10\sqrt2$$ or 
$$x_{3,4,5,6}=11\pm\sqrt{52\pm10\sqrt2}$$ and we got a maximal root:
$$11+\sqrt{52+10\sqrt2}.$$