# Some interesting observations on a sum of reciprocals

Tags: polynomials, convergence-divergence, roots

This [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2874645/let-m-be-the-largest-real-root-of-the-equation-frac3x-3-frac5x-5-fra/2874652#2874652) is the motivation for this post.

---

> Consider the following equation $$\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x-2}+\cdots+\frac1{x-k}=\frac1{x-k-1}$$ where $k>1$.
>
> **My claims:**
>
> 1. There are $k$ solutions, all of which are real.
> 2. Let $x_{\min}$ be the minimum value of these $k$ solutions. Then as $k\to\infty$, $x_{\min}$ converges. (If it does, to what value does it converge?)
> 3. As $k\to\infty$, all of the solutions get closer and closer to an integer, which is bounded below. Furthermore, these integers will be $1, 2, 3, \cdots, k-1, k+1$.

To see these patterns, I provide the solutions of $x$ below. I used W|A for $k\ge4$. The values in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ are those of $x_{\min}$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c}k&2&3&4&5&6\\\hline x&4.414&4.879&5.691&6.592&7.530\\&\color{blue}{1.585}&2.652&3.686&4.701&5.722\\&&\color{blue}{1.468}&2.545&3.588&4.615\\&&&\color{blue}{1.411}&2.487&3.531\\&&&&\color{blue}{1.376}&2.449\\&&&&&\color{blue}{1.352}\end{array}$$

Also, when $k=2$, the polynomial in question is $x^2-6x+7$, and when $k=3$, it is $x^3-9x^2+24x-19$.

The reason why I think $x_{\min}$ converges is because the difference between the current one and the previous gets smaller and smaller as $k$ increases.

---

> **Are my claims true?**

Comment: It is easy to prove that it has at least $k-1$ distinct real soutions

Comment: and also it is true that $1<x_{min}<2$ for every $k$ and it converges to 1

Comment: @Exodd:  if you do that you know it has $k$ distinct solutions because of the limits of each side as $x \to \pm \infty$

Comment: The method I used (removing the asymptotes) has been the basis of significant improvements in chemical engineering calculations (in particular for the so-called Rachford-Rice and Underwood equations). I have published quite a lor of papers for these. I had a lot of fun with your (may I confess that I cannot resist an equation ?). Cheers.

Comment: I updated my answer for some improvements. Cheers and thanks for the problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You're welcome. I'm glad you enjoyed working on this.

Comment: Nearly on $10k$ rep, I see.... hope you get there! Interesting observation, too! $(+1)$ $\color{darkorange}{\bigstar}$ :D

Comment: @user477343 thanks! I note that you have some great puzzles as well :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both your claims are true.

if you call 
$$
f(x) = \frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x-2}+\cdots+\frac1{x-k}-\frac1{x-k-1}
$$
then $f(1^+) = +\infty$, $f(2^-) = -\infty$ and $f$ is continuous in $(1,2)$, so it has a root in $(1,2)$. 
The same you can say about $(2,3)$, $(3,4), \cdots, (k-1,k)$, so there are at least $k-1$ real distinct roots. $f$ is also equivalent to a $k$-degree polynomial with the same root, but a $k$-degree polynomial with $k-1$ real roots has in reality $k$ real roots.

The last root lies in $(k+1,+\infty)$, since $f(k+1^+) = -\infty$ and $f(+\infty) = +\infty$.

The least root $x_{\min}$ must lie in $(1,2)$, since $f(x)<0$ for every $x<1$. Moreover, 
$$
f(x) = 0\implies x = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac1{x-k-1}-\frac1{x-2}-\cdots-\frac1{x-k}}
$$
and knowing $1<x<2$, we infer $\frac1{x-k-1}>\frac1{x-2}$ and
$$
1<x = 1 + \frac{1}{\frac1{x-k-1}-\frac1{x-2}-\cdots-\frac1{x-k}}
< 1 - \frac{1}{\frac1{x-3}+\cdots+\frac1{x-k}}\to 1
$$
so $x_{\min}$ converges to $1$

---

About the third claim, notice that you may repeat the same argument for any root except the biggest. Let us say that $x_r$ is the $r-th$ root, with $r<k$, and we know that $r<x_r<r+1$. 
$$
f(x_r) = 0\implies x_r = r + \frac{1}{\frac1{x_r-k-1}-\frac1{x_r-1}-\cdots-\frac1{x_r-k}}
$$
but $\frac1{x_r-k-1}>\frac1{x_r-1}$  holds, so
$$
r<x_r = r + \frac{1}{\frac1{x_r-k-1}-\frac1{x_r-1}-\cdots-\frac1{x_r-k}}
< r - \frac{1}{\frac1{x_r-2}+\cdots+\frac1{x_r-k}}\to r
$$
so $x_r$ converges to $r$.

For the biggest root, we know $k+1<x_k$ and
$$
f(x_k) = 0\implies k+1 < x_k = k+1 + \frac{1}{\frac1{x_k-1}+\cdots+\frac1{x_k-k}} \to k+1
$$

Comment: I would've argued that the LHS is continuous, monotone, and ranges from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ between natural numbers, while the RHS is continuous and monotone, and since the LHS is asymptotically larger than the RHS as $x\to\infty$, there must be a solution $x>k+1$, where the LHS is less than the RHS. In any case, sound argument.

Comment: I think they're quite equivalent. Now I'm wondering if $x_{max}$  converges to $k+1$

Comment: @Exodd Nice proofs. The third claim of converging to integers extends the claim $x_{\min}$ to all solutions of $x$. I strongly believe that it's true after plotting in Desmos, but I can't construct a rigorous proof for it.

Comment: Hard to exactly say what that's supposed to mean, $k+1$ is a moving target :P

Comment: Let's say $x_{max}(k)-k-1 = o_k(1)$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire One can rearrange Exodd's argument about $x_{\text{min}}\to1$ to any other natural less than $k$.

Comment: To be hand-wavy about the maximum root, the LHS is positive and unbounded in $k$, so the RHS must also be positive and unbounded in $k$.

Comment: Ok, now I'm convinced that the roots converge to $1,2,3,\dots,k-2,k-1,k+1$ (they skip $k$)

Comment: I think that the statement is if the $j$th smallest roof of $f_k$ is $_kx_j,$ then $\lim_{k\to\infty}{_kx_j}=j$

Answer (score 5):

For the base case,
$$\tag1f_2(x)=\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x-2}-\frac1{x-3}, $$
one readily verifies that there is a root in $(1,2)$ and a root $x^*$ in $(3,+\infty)$.

If we multiply out the denominators of
$$f_k(x)=\frac1{x-1}+\frac1{x-2}+\ldots+\frac1{x-k}-\frac1{x-k-1},$$
we obtain the equation 
$$\tag2(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k-1)f_k(x)=0,$$
which is a polynomial of degree (at most) $k$, so we expect $k$ solutions, but some of these may be complex or repeated or happen to be among $\{1,2,\ldots, k+1\}$ and thus not allowed for the original equation.
But $f_k(x)$
has simple poles with jumps from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ at $1,2,3,\ldots, k$, and a simple pole with jump from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$ at $k+1$, and is continuous otherwise. It follows that there is (at least) one real root in $(1,2)$, at least one in in $(2,3)$, etc. up to $(k-1,k)$, so there are at least $k-1$ distinct real roots.
Additionally, for $x>k+1$ and $k\ge2$, we have
$$f_k(x)\ge f_2(x+k-2).$$
It follows that there is another real root between $k+1$ and $x^*+k-2$.
So indeed, we have $k$ distinct real roots.

From the aboive, the smallest root is always in $(1,2)$.
If follows from $f_{k+1}(x)>f_k(x)$ for $x\in(1,2)$ and the fact that all $f_k$ are strictly decreasing there, that $x_\min $ decreases with increasing $k$. As a decreasing bounded sequence, it does have a limit.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you look for the first zero of function
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac 1{x-i}-\frac1 {x-k-1}$$ which can write, using harmonic numbers,
$$f(x)=H_{-x}-H_{k-x}-\frac{1}{x-k-1}$$ remove the asymptotes using
$$g(x)=(x-1)(x-2)f(x)=2x-3+(x-1)(x-2)\left(H_{2-x}-H_{k-x}-\frac{1}{x-k-1} \right)$$ You can approximate the solution using a Taylor expansion around $x=1$ and get
$$g(x)=-1+(x-1) \left(-\frac{1}{k}+\psi ^{(0)}(k)+\gamma
   +1\right)+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, this gives as an *approximation*
$$x_{est}=1+\frac{k}{k\left(\gamma  +1+ \psi ^{(0)}(k)\right)-1}$$ which seems to be "decent"  (and, for sure, confirms your claims).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & x_{est} &  x_{sol} \\
 2  & 1.66667 & 1.58579 \\
 3  & 1.46154 & 1.46791 \\
 4  & 1.38710 & 1.41082 \\
 5  & 1.34682 & 1.37605 \\
 6  & 1.32086 & 1.35209 \\
 7  & 1.30238 & 1.33430 \\
 8  & 1.28836 & 1.32040 \\
 9  & 1.27726 & 1.30914 \\
 10 & 1.26817 & 1.29976 \\
 11 & 1.26055 & 1.29179 \\
 12 & 1.25403 & 1.28489 \\
 13 & 1.24837 & 1.27884 \\
 14 & 1.24339 & 1.27347 \\
 15 & 1.23895 & 1.26867 \\
 16 & 1.23498 & 1.26433 \\
 17 & 1.23138 & 1.26039 \\
 18 & 1.22810 & 1.25678 \\
 19 & 1.22510 & 1.25346 \\
 20 & 1.22233 & 1.25039
\end{array}
\right)$$ For infinitely large values of $k$, the asymptotics of the estimate would be
$$x_{est}=1+\frac{1}{\log \left({k}\right)+\gamma +1}$$

For $k=1000$, the exact solution is $1.12955$ while the first approximation gives $1.11788$ and the second $1.11786$.

Using such estimates would make Newton method converging quite fast (shown below for $k=1000$).

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.117855442 \\
 1 & 1.129429575 \\
 2 & 1.129545489 \\
 3 & 1.129545500
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

We can obtain much better approximations if, instead of using a Taylor expansion of $g(x)$ to $O\left((x-1)^2\right)$, we build the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant (which is equivalent to an  $O\left((x-1)^3\right)$ Taylor expansion). This would lead to
$$x=1+ \frac{6 (k+k (\psi ^{(0)}(k)+\gamma )-1)}{\pi ^2 k+6 (k+\gamma  (\gamma 
   k+k-2)-1)-6 k \psi ^{(1)}(k)+6 \psi ^{(0)}(k) (2 \gamma  k+k+k \psi
   ^{(0)}(k)-2)}$$ Repeating the same calculations as above, the results are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & x_{est} &  x_{sol} \\
 2  & 1.60000 & 1.58579 \\
 3  & 1.46429 & 1.46791 \\
 4  & 1.40435 & 1.41082 \\
 5  & 1.36900 & 1.37605 \\
 6  & 1.34504 & 1.35209 \\
 7  & 1.32741 & 1.33430 \\
 8  & 1.31371 & 1.32040 \\
 9  & 1.30266 & 1.30914 \\
 10 & 1.29348 & 1.29976 \\
 11 & 1.28569 & 1.29179 \\
 12 & 1.27897 & 1.28489 \\
 13 & 1.27308 & 1.27884 \\
 14 & 1.26787 & 1.27347 \\
 15 & 1.26320 & 1.26867 \\
 16 & 1.25899 & 1.26433 \\
 17 & 1.25516 & 1.26039 \\
 18 & 1.25166 & 1.25678 \\
 19 & 1.24844 & 1.25346 \\
 20 & 1.24547 & 1.25039
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $k=1000$, this would give as an estimate $1.12829$ for an exact value of  $1.12955$.

For infinitely large values of $k$, the asymptotics of the estimate would be
$$x_{est}=1+\frac{6 (\log (k)+\gamma +1)}{6 \log (k) (\log (k)+2 \gamma +1)+\pi ^2+6 \gamma 
   (1+\gamma )+6}$$

Comment: Interesting! What does that notation $\psi^{(0)}(k)$ mean by the way?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. This is "just" the digamma function.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. We use to write $\psi^{(n)}(k)$ for the polygamma function and, in usual notations,$\psi^{(0)}(k)=\psi(k)$